# How would I know that email has been sent or not via SendGrid in Django

Tags: django, email, exception, sendgrid

I am working on django and sending emails to multiple users at once. in the given scenario it only tells me that if it has sent or not.

I want to display the report of same page that how many  emails has sent to user successfully and how many not. more if i want to get details why email has failed to sent.

How would i do such things via **SENDGRID** APIs.

Comment: Perhaps you could start here: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/bounces.html

Comment: but what if i want the status at run time?

Comment: I doubt if you could get the status instantly going through SendGrid, especially if you're sending bulk emails.

Comment: The APi return the data based on dates. How would i know for specific bulk if the application is distributed and many admins doing the same task at same time. this is the conflict.

Comment: You're limited by what their API will return and how.

Comment: Is there any alternative in your mind?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67911/discussion-between-brandon-and-muhammad-taqi-hassan-bukhari).

Comment: If you end up sending a distinct SMTP message per using, you can attach a unique_arg, and use the Event Webhook to see the results.

https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/unique_arguments.html
https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html

Answer (score 2):

There are two options that I know of:

Connect to [SendGrid Event Webhooks](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html) and start parsing events for every email to flag ones that were not sent. I believe you can configure SendGrid to only send certain events, so if you're interested in bounces you don't need to worry about handling all events.

The second option is to use a service like [sendwithus](http://www.sendwithus.com) which will connect to your SendGrid account on your behalf and track all bounces/opens/clicks for you and provide a simpler API/UI to view the data. I believe they do this via SendGrid's webhooks, so it's effectively the same solution but written for you.

Happy to elaborate on either, I've used both before.

Comment: Can you elaborate the 2nd option to me. actually what it does behind the scenes and how secure is this?

Comment: Sure -- you create a SendGrid subuser and connect it to your sendwithus account. Then you use the sendwithus api (https://www.sendwithus.com/docs/api) to send templated emails through Sendgrid (the templates live inside sendwithus). It's effectively as secure as SendGrid, and since it's a subuser you can restrict access. I believe it's free to try, suggest giving it a shot. :)